# How to make an animation of appearance of the element from below?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have such code: https://codepen.io/mymddboeyws-knowledgemd-com/pen/KKovdxV

150th string in css

```
/* Animation */
.pricing-items-container{
    position: relative;
}
.pricing .pricing-items{
    margin-top: -190px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    /*transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;*/
}
.pricing .pricing-items.active{
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

I want the cards to be showed from below to up, but they like go from top to bottom/rolled up. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your card is transitioning that way because of your `margin-top` style.
You could add `margin-top` to the active cards, but the value of the active card `margin-top` should be lower to simulate the rolle-up effect.

```
/* Animation */
.pricing-items-container{
    position: relative;
}
.pricing .pricing-items{
    margin-top: -100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 0;
    transition: 1s;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    /*transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;*/
}
.pricing .pricing-items.active{
    margin-top: -190px;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```